# What does "firebase-functions@0.5.5 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~4.1.2 but none was installed"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using npm to install open source node.js package

At the end of the install npm outputs:

WARN firebase-functions@0.5.5 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~4.1.2 but none was installed.

What does this mean?

Comment: I did the command "npm install firebase-functions", and it seems the WARN is now gone, but based on what the warning stated, it seems backwards.

Comment: You are focusing on the "peer of" when you should take more notice of the versions of the modules. You likely had both installed but `firebase-admin` was of a later version (5.0.0 perhaps since that is the current latest?) And you fixed it by upgrading your `firebase-functions` to a version that works with a later version of firebase-admin.  (I'm guessing you have `firebase-functions@0.5.7` now if you check again `npm list firebase-functions`).  Then again, maybe I'm just making too many assumptions here.

Comment: The error looks like a [versioning](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/61) issue.

You can update either firebase-functions or firebase-admin to match the other one's version.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a [version mismatch issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/61).

Updating either one to match the other will work.